# Error when display ABPersonViewController

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I create ABPersonViewController like this :

```
ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] ;
picker.personViewDelegate = self;
picker.displayedPerson = person;
picker.displayedProperties=@[@(kABPersonPhoneProperty),@(kABPersonEmailProperty),@(kABPersonBirthdayProperty),@(kABPersonOrganizationProperty),@(kABPersonJobTitleProperty),@(kABPersonDepartmentProperty),@(kABPersonNoteProperty),@(kABPersonCreationDateProperty)];
// Allow users to edit the person’s information
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.allowsActions=YES;
```

And then i push that controller to from my navigation controller and got this error :

```
Assertion failure in +[CNContact propertyForPropertyID:], /SourceCache/AddressBookUI_Sim/AddressBookUI-1553.3.50/Framework/Sources/CNUIContact/CNContact.m:862
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to convert property ID "26" to CN property name'
```

I realize this error because i add kABPersonCreationDateProperty, but i don't know why. Can someone explain me about this?Thank You

Comment: have you checked whether that particular contact is having all those fields that you're querying?

Comment: yes, i already check and got the creation date from that (ABRecordRef)person.

Comment: The issue might be with date format, not really sure

Comment: Hopefully yes, but i think not, because the creation date value  auto generated when we create new contact.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, it was NOT necessary to check before which properties exist. This would be anyway VERY troublesome. I got the error only when I included the kABPersonKindProperty property.

Comment: Regarding my comment above: The error with the kABPersonKindProperty disappeared by now (after some modifications of the code at completely other places). So it seems to be an intermittent problem.